# Detect single or multiple word in one cell

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name **table1**.

```
 Id         |               Data
 1          |   Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4
```

Here's that I want to do.

In IF Statement if it detects **1 or more** values equal or similar to Column Data then it will proceed. And also it is possible to ignore the command(,) and spaces( ) when comparing to the variable to the value of the column data?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $sql = "SELECT id, Data FROM table1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data = $row["Data"];
            $repdata = array();
            foreach($data as $val){
               if(++$repdata[$val] > 1){
               return true;
            }
           }
           return false;
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer @amit but i found this solution in easiest way using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
$data = ('value1, value2, value3, value4, value5');

if(preg_match('[value1|value2]', $row->column_name))
```